# Is there a jQuery window plugin like Prototype window?

Tags: jquery, plugins, popup, window

Hi
I like this plugin for windows and dialogs: http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/samples.html
But I want to use just jquery, not both (jquery and scriptaculous). I'm looking for a jquery plugin which has all features. I need a modal window, which can be resized, dropped, minimized, maximized, restored. I found just one plugin: http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/ but it has not a modal feature!

May be you know, is there another jquery plungin which has all features I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this has all the functionality I think you are looking for. It extends the JQuery UI Dialog with maximize and minimize functions.

http://carvalhar.com/componente/jQueryDialogr/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You've probably looked at jQuery UI already, but I thought I'd add the link anyway as it has many of the features you describe (although not the max/minmimize)...

[jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Comment: Yes, I looked at this, but it hasn't mex/miniminze ... :(